# React/Redux load paged ID list, then load page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react component in a Redux enabled application that starts by loading a list of ID's in a 2D array. (Each "page" is represented by an element of the outer array [1rst dimension])

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { loadInsiderPage, loadInsiderInfo } from "../../actions/insider";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import IndividualInsider from "./individual";

import Paginate from "../common/paginate";

class InsiderList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.insiderIds.length > 0) {
      this.props.loadInsiderPage(this.props.insiderIds[0]);
    } else {
      this.props.loadInsiderInfo();
    }
  }
  render() {
    let { insiderIds, insiders } = this.props;
    let insiderFormat = insiders.map(x => {
      return <IndividualInsider key={x._id} insider={x} />;
    });
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <Paginate
            pages={insiderIds}
            changePage={this.props.loadInsiderPage}
          />
          {insiderFormat}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { loadInsiderPage, loadInsiderInfo }
)(InsiderList);
```

This component will load the ID list if it's not filled by running the `loadInsiderInfo()` action, and if the ID list is not empty, it will trigger the page to be populated by running the `loadInsiderPage()` action which takes in a page from the ID list.

How can I have this trigger properly after the ID list has been loaded?

I was thinking I could do it in `componentWillReceiveProps()` but I'm not sure where to go with the `nextProps` property.

My actions are as follows:

```
export const loadInsiderInfo = () => dispatch => {
  Axios.get("insider/list/pages/25")
    .then(list => {
      dispatch({ type: LOAD_INSIDER_LIST, payload: list.data });
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: GET_ERRORS, payload: err }));
};

export const loadInsiderPage = page => dispatch => {
  console.log(page);
  Axios.post("insider/page", { page })
    .then(res => dispatch({ type: LOAD_INSIDER_PAGE, payload: res.data }))
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: GET_ERRORS, payload: err }));
};
```

Both simply grab data from the API and load it into the reducer.

The big issue that I'm coming across is that the Component will sometimes have props passed that keep the `loadInsiderPage` action from being called with a `page` object passed in.

Comment: can you add your actions as well? does your action contain only one api call that gets the data?

Comment: getting that in there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action creator `loadInsiderInfo()` you can accept a param for the current page ID. Now when the Info is loaded, within this action creator you can dispatch another action by calling `loadInsiderPage(id)` in it. This way your page info is loaded for the first time by the insider info action creator itself.

Something like this:

```
export const loadInsiderInfo = (id) => dispatch => {
  Axios.get("insider/list/pages/25")
    .then(list => {
      dispatch({ type: LOAD_INSIDER_LIST, payload: list.data });
      if(<your-data-loaded>){
         loadInsiderPage(id)(dispatch);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: GET_ERRORS, payload: err }));
};
```

Now only call `loadInsiderInfo(id)` once, when there is no info loaded yet. For every other time, directly dispatch the `loadInsiderPage(id)` action instead. This way you handle every case, after the insider info data has been loaded.